# How to delete the outer circles in an image without affecting the rest of the image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have an image similar to the image shown below.
[image]

I want to delete both the black and red circles of the image without affecting the red squares inside the image (as both red circle and red squares are of the same pixel value).

I have tried using `cv2.HoughCircles` to detect the red circle and tried converting it to black color but some portion of the red circle remains unchanged as shown.

[image]

And this is the code I used for that.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("13-14.png")
output = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.3, 145)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 0 , 0), 4)

cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([image, output]))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

The sample output I am looking for is kind of this image (either color or greyscale).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the squares seem to be "significantly" larger than the circles' thickness, simple morphological opening using some rectangular kernel (to maintain the shape of the squares) should work here.

That'd be my solution:

```py
import cv2
from skimage import io          # Only needed for web grabbing images; for local images, use cv2.imread(...)

# Read provided example image
image = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfUOF.png'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

# Mask non-white content
_, mask = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 252, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Apply morphological opening with 5x5 rectangular kernel to get rid of the circles
mod = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5)))

# Obtain mask of parts to be erased from the difference of both masks
erase = mask - mod

# Set corresponding pixels in image to white
image[erase == 255] = (255, 255, 255)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('mod', mod)
cv2.imshow('erase', erase)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The non-white content `mask` looks like this:

[image: Mask]

The modified mask after the opening `mod` looks like this:

[image: Modified mask]

The difference of both are parts to be erased (`erase`):

[image: To be erased]

Finally, all masked pixels are set to white:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: @HansHirse Thank you. That solved my problem exactly!!

Answer (score 3):

Floodfill from top-left corner, filling first with black, then with white, then with red:

[image]

As it happens, I did it with **ImageMagick** as below, but you can do just the same with a Python package:

```
magick circles.png \
   -fill black -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" \
   -fill white -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" \
   -fill red   -draw "color 0,0 floodfill" result.png
```

[image]

Comment: And how to get rid of the red background, since it's connected to one of the red squares? I had the same idea in the beginning, but was running into that issue.

Comment: @HansHirse Yes, I'd probably end up doing some morphology too, to erode the red so it doesn't touch.

Comment: Hello, @Mark Setchell Thank you for your response. Could you please let me know what exactly is the python package and how can I install that( is there a pip installer available)?

Comment: You could use **OpenCV**, or **skimage** or **Wand**, I believe they all offer *"flood fill"* functionality.